# Generator | Trigger database INSERT after last yield

Tags: python-3.x

I want my generator to return a value I can test for **when the generator context is finished**.

Every 1000 rows I `INSERT`, however some XML files produce fewer than 1000 rows and therefore the condition is never met.

I have reduced this to pseudocode for simplicity:

```
def f():
    for e in xml:
        yield e

for i, e in enumerate(f(), 1):
    if i%1000==0:
        db_client.insert()
```

I have tried testing `e` for `None` but alas this was never the case, the function default return was not included. I'm not sure how to capture `StopIteration`.

Comment: Why don't you do an additional ``db_client.insert()`` *after* the loop? The current code seems to miss any trailing data anyways, e.g. for 1200 items the last 200 are not inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I use % modulus operator. Otherwise, i don't want additional calls to INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `yield StopIteration` at end of function.

Pseudocode example:

```
def f():
    for e in xml:
        yield e
    yield StopIteration


for i, e in enumerate(f(), 1):
    if i%1000==0 or e==StopIteration:
        db_client.insert()
```

I am unsure as to whether this is good practice.